# How to access value passes from tiles definition to the layout page

Tags: jsp, struts, tiles

I need to display information in the layout page depending upon the current page.

I have added the attribute in current page definition as

```
<put name="flag" value="false"/>
```

Now I am not getting how to access this information in the layout page and render it accordingly

I am new to tile and struts so please help..

Answer (score 2):

To make available a tiles attribute into the jsp use the useAttribute tag.

see

tiles-3 – http://tiles.apache.org/framework/tiles-jsp/tlddoc/tilesx/useAttribute.html

tiles-2 – http://tiles.apache.org/2.2/framework/tiles-jsp/tlddoc/tiles/useAttribute.html

Answer (score 0):

Why you are setting this value in tiles definition? It is easy to set the values in your action either by using form or session, so you can get it in your jsp page for rendering. Is it any specific reason to set the values in tiles?